Obtain Sendgrid reputation by the API
There is an API endpoint https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/subusers/reputations but we don't use subusers and I want the reputation figure that is shown at the bottom-left of https://app.sendgrid.com/ when you're logged-in.
I've tried SG support but am not getting a straight answer from them.

This page shows how to obtain the account reputation.
